# Pi 4 (8GB) loses wifi when plugging large capacity USB

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-4

My RPI 4 (8 GB) boots fine, wifi stable and all seems to work with no issues. I purchased a few 256 GB Samsung USB 3.1 sticks to extend storage. But whenever I plug in one or two (as wanted), wifi won't start. (I don't want to mess hot-plugging or unplugging them). I'm able to access the USBs so they should be good.
Power down, remove sticks, boot up: wifi merrily OK.

Power supply (Pimoroni) should be rated well enough (3A).

A second RPI 4 (4 GB) does just fine (wifi OK) with the same arrangement (2 x USB), yet another 4 GB one with one of same sticks is also OK.

Logs don't seem helpful so far, although I don't exactly know where to look. dmesg doesn't even report a wlan* device.

Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get a powered hub seems to be the "offical" advice I always see on their forum when talking of drives plugged into it. These things are so flaky with their USB if I plug in my keyboard I cannot boot, is my problem with the Pi 4 8GB I have with their implementation of USB. My power supply in the Canakit I got is rated for 3.5A.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `dmesg` log for hints about the WiFi driver (`brcmfmac`). You may also want to re-check the log after manually reloading it (`sudo rmmod brcmfmac; sudo modprobe brcmfmac`).